# Ontodia library - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I'm working with [**Ontodia javascript library**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ontodia) to present my **graphdb** rdf data set.

There's this error I couldnt find the cause of it, which happens onload:
[image]

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

This function is exactly as the DOCS describes you should connect to your sparql endpoint.

```
function onWorkspaceMounted(workspace) {
  if (!workspace) {
    return;
  }
  workspace.getModel().importLayout({
    dataProvider: new SparqlDataProvider(
      {
        endpointUrl: REACT_APP_API_URL + "/sparql/query",
        imagePropertyUris: ["http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/img"],
        queryMethod: SparqlQueryMethod.GET,
        queryFunction: ontodiaQueryFunction
      },
      OWLStatsSettings
    )
  });
}
```

I have the feeling something is not valid with the response I get from `...queryFunction: ontodiaQueryFunction`, and Ontodia might have a problem dealing with it, but that's just a guess. Though I did log the resolved promise of `ontodiaQueryFuncion` to see I get a legit response, and it does look legit.

Did you run into a similar issue? or familiar with this error?

Comment: Never heard about this library, but I guess it's a very tool specific problem and according to their [homepage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ontodia), you should get faster and maybe "better" support if you ask the devs directly via email: mailto:ontodia-people@vismart.biz

Comment: @AKSW, *"Never heard about this library"* — see https://metaphacts.com/news/99-metaphacts-acquires-vismart :-)

Comment: @StanislavKralin thank's for the pointer. But honestly, I didn't know about it because there are too many visualization libs and this was just one among others based on a demo/poster publication from ISWC 2015. Fun fact, I attended this conference but as usual way too many posters and demos at conferences, so I keep forgetting all the cool tools and APIs I'm not using in my daily job. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix here: https://github.com/metaphacts/ontodia/issues/187

and BTW, they say this was fixed in v0.9.9

Answer (score 0):

You can check graphdb npm package: [graphdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphdb) - "A GraphDB and RDF4J data access library written in JavaScript to be used in Node.js."